# One request to servlet that can have two types of response

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I have a thread running on my server (I'm using Tomcat and Java files) and when a user makes a request the server can respond with two types of responses depending on the state of the thread. The responses should be in JSON and I'm using the Jersey library and the Servlet looks something like:

```
@GET
@Path("init")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public initResponse respondAsReady() {
    return initRes;
}
```

this is just an example but the problem is I am limited to using one type of JSON response (in this case `initResponse`) but I need to be able to return another type of response (say `initResponse2`) which is a different type of JSON. And in other cases I need to respond with either just an integer or with a JSON object. So how can I structure my backend so that it can handle requests and return two possible responses?

Comment: Hit: `initResponse` is not a valid Java class name.

Comment: initResponse is the class that represents the JSON returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@GET
@Path("init")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON , MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
public Response respondAsReady() {
    if(/*condition*/)}
        //In case of a JSON response
        return Response.ok(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
    if(/*condition*/){
        //In case of an integer response
        return Response.ok(text, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: so if the method returns two different jsons i should do this?:     if(/*condition*/)}
        //In case of a JSON response
        return Response.ok(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
    if(/*condition*/){
        //In case of an integer response
         return Response.ok(json2, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }

Answer (score 1):

Each endpoint that you have should have `@Consumes` annotation, this annotation defines the media types that the methods of a resource class or MessageBodyReader can accept, also you need to use `@Produces` this defines the media type(s) that the methods of a resource class or MessageBodyWriter can produce

```
@GET
@Path("init")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public InitResponse respondAsReady() {
    return new InitResponse;
}

@GET
@Path("init")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String respondAsReady() {
    return new String("5");
}
```

Using this jersey select the method based on the Accept header in the request, so be sure to send it with your request. Read this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipzh/index.html) to learn more about it

If your client accept only 'text/plain' the second endpoint will be executed. Just past this value in the Accept header.

Comment: In my case the client doesn't know which response will be coming so you can't put that in the header of the request. The response type is determined on the server side by a thread running on the server.